# Cocoapod swifty json issue

Tags: swift, cocoapods, dependency-management, swifty-json

I am having some difficulty with dependency management with my project. I currently have managed to get Alamofire to work with great success and now I wish to add a new dependency to my project.

Following the guide here - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON it tells me to add the following to my pod file

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Relocate' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
end
```

This means my pod file now looks as follows;

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Relocate' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
end
```

The issue is, when i run the `pod install` command i get the following error

```
Rickis-iMac:Relocate rickilambert$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `SwiftyJSON (~> 2.2.1)` required by `Podfile`
```

Does anyone know how i might resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do my Podfiles exactly like this below and have never had an issue. Try pasting this in and running `pod install`

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using version 2.2.0 worked - not sure what is wrong with 2.2.1 mind you.

Comment: Your problem has to be an issue with the spec repo of CocoaPods

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove SwiftyJSON V 2.2.1 (from your project). By running pod install with the following podfile:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
end

target 'AppNameTests' do

end
```

Then you have to add SwiftyJSON V 2.2.0 to your podfile then running pod install again:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
end

target 'AppNameTests' do

end
```

I hope this helps, Happy coding.